# Setting up Eureka for non-AWS datacenter

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have setup Eureka with 2 peers, after about 5 minutes I see this message appear in the UI:

> EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.

When I look at the output from one of the running instances of Eureka, I see this:

```
2015-11-11 14:46:47.276  INFO 32748 --- [pool-5-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2015-11-11 14:56:17.427  WARN 32748 --- [eerNodesUpdater] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : The replica size seems to be empty. Check the route 53 DNS Registry
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, Eureka thinks it is configured at AWS.  I'm unable to find anything in the `application.yml` to indicate this.

Any ideas on what I'm missing in the config?

```
server:
  port: 80

eureka:
  datacenter: boston
  instance:
    hostname: eureka03.domain.com
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
---
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka01.domain.com
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Comment: The reference to route53 is just in an message. That happens when there are no peers setup.

Comment: Is my peer setup in the application.yml file incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue with my application.yml to get peers setup.  Here's the proper application.yml if anyone runs into the same issue.

application.yml on peer1

```
server:
  port: 80

eureka:
  datacenter: boston
  instance:
    hostname: eureka01
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka03/eureka/
```

application.yml on peer2

```
server:
  port: 80

eureka:
  datacenter: boston
  instance:
    hostname: eureka03
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka01/eureka/
```

Comment: are eureka03 and eureka01 reachable hosts?

Comment: Still having issues with the peering.  The hosts can talk to each other, but the eureka data is not replicated.  I can see services and hosts registered on eureka01, and missing on eureka03.  On one of the peers, I see replication set to false.   I see similar log entries for services registered. INFO 32313 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance EUREKA/eureka01:eureka:80 with status UP (replication=false)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are missing instanceId which helps eureka to identifies nodes:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: app56.test.online.eniro
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: EUREKA01_${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http:///eureka01/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

After about 5 minutes, I see this in the web ui.  EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.

I have also verified the peers can talk to each other.  Here's what I see in the eureka output.

```
2015-11-13 09:08:39.928  WARN 860 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: EUREKA - eureka03:eureka:80
2015-11-13 09:08:39.928  WARN 860 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew): EUREKA - eureka03:eureka:80
2015-11-13 09:08:40.451  INFO 860 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance EUREKA/eureka03:eureka:80 with status UP (replication=true)
2015-11-13 09:08:43.066  WARN 860 --- [ka01.ctct.net-6] c.n.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTask       : The replication of task EUREKA/eureka01:eureka:80:Heartbeat@eureka01 failed with response code 404
2015-11-13 09:08:43.066  WARN 860 --- [ka01.ctct.net-6] c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : EUREKA/eureka01:eureka:80:Heartbeat@eureka01: missing entry.
2015-11-13 09:08:43.066  WARN 860 --- [ka01.ctct.net-6] c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : EUREKA/eureka01:eureka:80:Heartbeat@p2-dev-eureka01.ctct.net: cannot find instance id eureka01:eureka:80 and hence replicating the instance with status UP
```

Here's my application.yml for the 2 peers

peer1

```
server:
  port: 80

eureka:
  datacenter: bedford
  instance:
    hostname: eureka01
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: EUREKA01_${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka03/eureka/
```

peer2

```
server:
  port: 80

eureka:
  datacenter: bedford
  instance:
    hostname: eureka03
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: EUREKA03_${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka01/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run the 3 eureka servers on my localhost, however the hostname being localhost for all 3 caused the above noted error. The error was resolved When I changed it by creating hostname entries in hosts file